# If the user pauses a video, I need to know the exact point where it was paused and to store it. How?

Tags: javascript, youtube

If I am running a youtube video with javascript, I can have an event fire every time the user pauses the video.  But how do I capture the point in the video where he hit PAUSE?  I need a number that reflects how far he was into the video before he paused.
Thanks,

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970013/getting-current-youtube-video-time

Comment: I think the stackoverflow question of strille provided the answer.