# Get current time of Youtube Video on youtube.com (e.g. document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime())

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, youtube

I'm creating a Google Chrome extension that relies on knowing the current time of a video being played on 'youtube.com'. I know, in principle, that `document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime()` should return this, but invoking this in a content script injected into the page produces:

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime is not a
>   function(…)

I am able to run the command in the Chrome console and get a proper return value.

And before this is flagged up as a duplicate question, I want to point out that I'm talking about doing this on 'youtube.com'. I dont know if I should expect special behavior, but this is definitely a different context than other questions I've found on stackoverflow.

To help, below is the simplest code I could come up with to reproduce this problem. To get it working, you'll need to [load this as an unpacked extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked). Then navigate to any youtube video. Click on the extension icon and click the "Start The Test" button. Also make sure you have the console open (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

Thanks in advance for suggestions for how to make this method work, or another way I can get the info I need (e.g. I looked into getting the share at time value but couldnt figure that one out). As a last resort, I'm considering replacing the youtube player with my own iframe and trying that way.

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <script src='popup.js'></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='button' id='start' value='Start The Test'></input>
    <p id="messages"></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
// Add listener for start button
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener('click', process_video);
});


function process_video() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'test.js'});
}
```

test.js

```
player = document.getElementById('movie_player');
console.log(player);
console.log(player.getCurrentTime()); // ERROR IN QUESTION IS PRODUCED WITH THIS COMMAND
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "It's a placeholder",
  "description": "This is only a test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "My Test"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://localhost/*",
    "https://www.youtube.com/*"
  ]

}
```

Comment: Did you try the currentTime property? See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/av_prop_currenttime.asp

Comment: Seems to work in my test script! I will post a tentative answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Charlie Dalsass (see comments below my question), I think I have an answer!

test.js

```
video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0];
console.log(video);
console.log(video.currentTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works in 2020:

```
// 1. ytplayer code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#IFrame_Player_API
var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
  }
// 2. get player.playerInfo.currentTime
window.onclick = () => {
  console.log(player);
  alert(player.playerInfo.currentTime);
}
```

[see it live on codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/wvKdqaY?editors=1010)