# Getting current time of embedded iframe youtube player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Here i have tried as follows:

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="player" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7a_CVFRqYv4?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

**Script**

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('player');}
```

Here i want to such action like when the player timing reaches 6 seconds,i want to change the src of the iframe.

Answer (score 7):

This thread describes how you can get the current playing time of a video using the YouTube API [Getting Current YouTube Video Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970013/getting-current-youtube-video-time)

Then maybe use setInterval() to run every second to check the value of getCurrentTime() from the API and if value = 6 set the src to the new video.

Comment: i don't want to use the setTimeout() function buddy,because the person,who seek the video into starting then also it should respond the same process.

Comment: So you don't want to respond to a specific time in the video eg. at the 6s mark change src to x? The timeout would only be used to periodically check the value of ytplayer.getCurrentTime();

Answer (score 1):

this should be solved with `setInterval()`, not `setTimeout()`.

using the latest youtube iFrame API:

```
var player;
var checkInt; // save this as a var in this scope so we can clear it later
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player('player');
   startInterval()
}

function startInterval() {
   //checks every 100ms to see if the video has reached 6s
   checkInt = setInterval(function() {
      if (player.getCurrentTime() > 6) {
         changeSrc();
         clearInterval(checkInt);
      };
   }, 100)
}

function changeSrc() {
   player.loadVideoById(xxxxx);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

call below function when your video is starting playing

```
function StartVideo(){
setTimeout("ChangeLinkUrl()", 6000);
}

function ChangeLinkUrl(){
var elem = document.getElementById('YourFrameID');
 elem.src = "newSorceURL";
}
```