# JavaScript Error updating progress.value

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

I have the following `interval` which updates the progress value while a YouTube video is playing. It works fine most of the cases but in some other cases the progress does weird things like going back and forth and I get the following error in the console.

`NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation.`

This occurs in all browsers and it mostly happens when I load a new video.

```
if(player) {
    player.loadVideoById({'videoId': data.yt_id});
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening and how can I fix this?

```
var value = 0;
var duration = player.getDuration();
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

var to = setInterval(function() {
    value = 1 / duration * player.getCurrentTime();
    progress.value = value;
}, 250);
```

The error fires on: `progress.value = value;`

`progress` is a `<progress>` element.

console.log():

```
value: 0.02622895199857715
youtube.js:104 player.getCurrentTime(): 5.417367
youtube.js:103 value: 0.02746555095910624
youtube.js:104 player.getCurrentTime(): 5.672776
youtube.js:103 value: 0.02870214991963533
youtube.js:104 player.getCurrentTime(): 5.928185
youtube.js:103 value: 0.029826330792843594
youtube.js:104 player.getCurrentTime(): 6.160375
```

Comment: What line is the error triggering on?

Comment: The error fires on: `progress.value = value;` @PatrickEvans

Comment: What is progress? `<progress>` element?

Comment: Yes It is a `<progress>` element.

Comment: Can you console.log out "1 / duration * player.getCurrentTime()" so we can see what that value is?  Wondering if progress needs an int between 0 and progress.Maximum

Comment: It doesen't print nothing in  Safari. It prints `0.3744603598331141` and so on in Chrome and Firefox and in Firefox it gives this error: `TypeError: Value being assigned to HTMLProgressElement.value is not a finite floating-point value.` @bri

Comment: OK.  One last question:  for any given moment (or 2 or 3), can you log out and tell us what duration is (eg - the value) and what getCurrentTime() is yielding (eg - the value).

Comment: See the updated question. @bri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add this as a comment, but it might get a little long.  May help you to go back to basics on this one and use some Integer values for progress object.

**Progress Basics**

I've always used progress object like this:

```
<progress id="myProgressBar" value="1" max="100"></progress>
```

Then, set progress.value as an integer between 0 and 100 (or whatever MAX is) ...

```
document.getElementById("myProgressBar").value = 10;
// code ...
document.getElementById("myProgressBar").value = 20;
 // code...
document.getElementById("myProgressBar").value = 30;
// etc ...
```

**YouTube API**

According to [this super helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6970068/4747123):

```
player.getCurrentTime():Number
```

> Returns the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing.

```
player.getDuration():Number
```

> Returns the duration in seconds of the currently playing video. Note
>   that getDuration() will return 0 until the video's metadata is loaded,
>   which normally happens just after the video starts playing.

**Your Code**

So, now we know (because stackoverflow SAID so) that `duration` is in seconds and we know (ibid) that `player.getCurrentTime()` is also yielding seconds.  Given those facts, we can just do the following:

```
var duration = player.getDuration();
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
if(duration!=undefined) { progress.max = parseInt(duration); }

var to = setInterval(function() {
    //just in case we got "0" last time.
    if(duration==undefined || duration == 0) {
       duration = player.getDuration(); 
       if(duration==undefined || duration==0) { return; }
       progress.max = duration;
    }
    var currentProgress = parseInt(player.getCurrentTime());
    if(currentProgress <= duration) { progress.value = currentProgress; }
}, 1000);
```

Of course, this is TOTALLY UNTESTED code...  Like I said - it should really be a comment, but comments are so ... limited ;-).  I'd put loggers in that interval code to see what values I'm getting for duration and for "currentProgress" as a next step...  Then, once it's working, I'd wrap it in a try to avoid hiccups from the youTube api.  But, that's just me.

**Oh.  And we are counting seconds, not 1/4 seconds...**

Oops... one last thing.  Since we are tracking seconds, I changed the interval to fire every second.  No reason to fire 4 times if my update interval isn't going to change.

If you wanted to track 1/10 of a second, I guess you could multiple both duration and getCurrentTime by 10 before you parseInt() them.

Hope it at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah.  That's probably my copy/paste idiocy.  can you ditch the :Number silliness (per the updated code) in the 3 places I copied it?  Try one more time.

Comment: Yeah but I still need to see this solution one by line to understand it better. @bri

Comment: Why the progress updates so slow even if I set to 50ms. @bri

Comment: Because you are using seconds as your progress meter (see that last part about multiplying duration and interval by 10 ...