# Get Current Time of Youtube Video Embedded in a Shiny app

Tags: javascript, shiny, youtube-api

I'm trying to store the current time of an embedded YouTube video in a shiny app upon a button click. Eventually I'd like to be able to bring that time data back into my R environment, but for now I'm just struggling with how to use the YouTube API within shiny.

I know from looking at the YouTube API and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970013/getting-current-youtube-video-time) question that you can get the current time of an embedded YouTube video. But when I wrap that video in the Shiny interface, the video has class *shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output* and I can't seem to find the underyling element  that corresponds to the YouTube video that's controllable by the api.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs()

  ,titlePanel("Hello Shiny!")

  ,sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("button", "Capture Video Time")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("video")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$video <- renderUI({
    HTML('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FR4QIeZaPeM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    runjs(
      "ytplayer = document.getElementById('video');
      var time = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
      alert(time);"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I expect is that when I click the button in the Shiny app, a window should pop up with the current time of the YouTube video, but instead nothing happens. So what my biggest need is to get that javascript code right inside the `runjs()` function (or something else if `runjs()` isn't appropriate here) so that I can actually find the video player's time. If you have any insight on how to bring that current time value back into my R environment it would be appreciated as well, but I can probably figure that part out once I get on the right track with this. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: It's not possible to access to the contents of an iframe pointing to another domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out myself. The issue was that I didn't set up the YouTube iframe API properly. Once I got that in place the rest of the code worked as I expected it to. For reference [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) is the documentation on the YouTube iframe API.

My working code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  headerPanel("New Application"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("getTime","Get Video Time")
  )
  ,mainPanel(
    uiOutput("video")
  )
))

server = function(input, output) {

  output$video <- renderUI({
    HTML(
      '<html>
        <body>
          <iframe id="existing-iframe"
              width="640" height="360"
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fmuUQCB3pAE?enablejsapi=1"
              frameborder="0"
          ></iframe>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            var tag = document.createElement(\'script\');
            tag.src = \'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\';
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
              player = new YT.Player(\'existing-iframe\');
            }
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>'
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$getTime,{
    runjs("alert(player.getCurrentTime())")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note the major difference is inside the HTML() wrapper beginning on line 18. I set up the iframe the same way but with `id="existing-iframe"` along with `enablejsapi=1` inside the URL. Then I needed the `<script>` tag below which had all of the JavaScript code I needed to get the app to recognize that I was using the YouTube iframe api. I also cleaned up the code inside the runjs() wrapper on line 44.