# How to go to specific time in youtube video programmatically in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api

I have a youtube video open on my browser. How to go to specific time stamp using javascript? I want to use this in chrome extension. I can give the t query in url but it reloads the whole page. I don't want to reload the whole page. Help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Write a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that finds the `video` element and sets its `currentTime`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the current YouTube video time without using YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919978/change-the-current-youtube-video-time-without-using-youtube-api)

Answer (score 3):

Try the `player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean)`  function:

```
document.getElementById("movie_player").seekTo(seconds,true);
```

Resources :https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls

credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6970039/9977151) for getting the player element

Comment: We can even use document.getElementById("movie_player").Currentime=seconds

Comment: @sandeysh Nope. it doesn't work. it only changes the variable Currentime it doesn't update the UI