# is it Possible to get current play time of a video Embedded using iFrame using JavaScript? How?

Tags: javascript, html, video

is there a way to track user's activity on a video embedded using iFrame tag?
the metadata am most interested in is current Duration, title, src...
ps: YouTube Player API did not work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

if it's for youtube as the tag suggest I'd consider using [youtube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)
as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970013/getting-current-youtube-video-time) you could use player.playerInfo.currentTime using that API.

now if it's just a `<video>` in html, you can use the [currentTime property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) you could also find the video element in your youtube iFrame and use that same property, it's gonna work. Basically as long as there is a video html element, you'll have access to this property

Comment: thank you for your help. my web app uses different videos from platforms mostly youtube. but I really want a way that works for different videos!!

Comment: you're welcome. if that answers you question feel free to select it as the answer :))

Comment: I added an edit to the answer, could solve the issue of multiple players